# Neo4J: CypherError during node creation: HTTP POST returned response 500

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to create a graph using Neo4J from the pandas data frame. I did ETL on all csv inputs and loaded into a target dataframe.

I have to create a graph which has input node (input name) and output node (output name) and edge (relationship- how it is connected).

I tried loading using csv, but it did not work. So, I am trying to create input nodes first from the pandas dataframe and output nodes next and edges later..

When i created input nodes first, it is executed successfully. However, when i use the same script (and change the names) for output node, it threw HTTP 500 error.
Cypher Error: HTTP POST returned response 500.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Am working on Google Colab.

the code that i used:

```
target_df
for index, row in inp_df.iterrows():
      node = Node (inpNodeName, name=row['name1'], city=row['cityInput'])
      graph.create(node)
for index1, row1 in out_df.iterrows():
      node1 = Node (outNodeName, name=row1['name1'], city=row1['cityOutput'])
      graph.create(node1)

Cypher Error: HTTP POST returned response 500
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code in the question, to show what you are actually running?

Comment: Does that help? let me know..